# TYPO3 8.7.17 ext:form - How to reuse Stage/Fieldset?

Tags: forms, typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

everybody!

I'm using the extension **form** and I want to create custom form elements.

I need to create multiple rows from a defined field list ... Something like this:

[image: Example of the custom form element I want.]

I have followed a [tutorial written by Manuel Selback](https://gist.github.com/manuelselbach/dc63abd313694c594d480b163a5f3053) in order to create custom form elements. I think I can reuse the FieldSet element. The problem is that my new item is not displaying well in the backend form editor (the field name and type are not showed).

[image: Custom field]

This is my code:

```
// EXT:my_ext/Configuration/Yaml/BaseSetup.yaml
TYPO3:
  CMS:
    Form:
      prototypes:
        standard:
          formEditor:
            formEditorPartials:
              FormElement-FieldRow: 'Stage/SimpleTemplate'

          formElementsDefinition:
            Form:
              renderingOptions:
                templateRootPaths:
                  100: 'EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/ext/form/Frontend/Templates/'
                partialRootPaths:
                  100: 'EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/ext/form/Frontend/Partials/'
                layoutRootPaths:
                  100: 'EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/ext/form/Frontend/Layouts/'
            FieldRow:
              __inheritances:
                10: 'TYPO3.CMS.Form.prototypes.standard.formElementsDefinition.Fieldset'


// EXT:my_ext/Configuration/Yaml/FormEditorSetup.yaml
TYPO3:
  CMS:
    Form:
      prototypes:
        standard:
          formEditor:
            dynamicRequireJsModules:
              additionalViewModelModules:

            formEditorPartials:
              FormElement-FieldRow: 'Stage/SimpleTemplate'

          formElementsDefinition:
            FieldRow:
              formEditor:
                label: 'formEditor.elements.FieldRow.label'
                group: container
                _isCompositeFormElement: true
                groupSorting: 1000
                iconIdentifier: 't3-form-icon-fieldrow'
                editors:
                  200:
                    label: 'formEditor.elements.FieldRow.editor.label.label'
                  230: null
                  800: null
```

Am I missing something?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

To correct the problem of displaying the name and field type, I edited EXT:my_ext/Configuration/Yaml/FormEditorSetup.yaml by adding the view model (TYPO3.CMS.Form.prototypes.standard.formEditor.dynamicRequireJsModules.additionalViewModelModules):

```
// EXT:my_ext/Configuration/Yaml/FormEditorSetup.yaml
TYPO3:
  CMS:
    Form:
      prototypes:
        standard:
          formEditor:
            dynamicRequireJsModules:
              additionalViewModelModules:
                - 'TYPO3/CMS/UnalForm/Backend/FormEditor/FieldRowViewModel'
```

After that, I created the JavaScript file *Resources/Public/JavaScript/Backend/FormEditor/FieldRowElementViewModel.js* to display my custom element correctly in the stage area.